# Spring @AliasFor is not working with annotation @RabbitListener

Tags: spring, spring-rabbit

I am trying to create a simple Meta-annotation which should act as a `@RabbitListener`

Here is my try:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@RabbitListener(errorHandler = "workerRabbitErrorHandler", returnExceptions = "true")
public @interface RabbitListenerEpp {
    @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class)
    String[] value() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class)
    String[] queues() default {};
}
```

And here is the way I would like to use it:

```java
@RabbitListenerEpp(queues= "${rabbit.worker.queue.domain.list}")
public DomainListResponseDto execute(Object arg){
//...
}
```

but the `@AliasFor` doesn't work. 
My Meta-annotation is working (if I specifie the queues in the `@RabbitListener` on the `@RabbitListenerEpp` annotation it works).
But I would like to be able to override the queues when I use `@RabbbitListenerEpp`

Comment: I opened a GitHub issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `attribute` as well as `annotation` to your `@AliasFor`s.

```
@AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class, attribute = "queues")
String[] value() default {};

@AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class, attribute = "queues")
String[] queues() default {};
```

But it still doesn't work.

I opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1136).

**EDIT**

Here is a work-around...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So59546604Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So59546604Application.class, args);
    }

    @RabbitListenerEpp("foo")
    void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {
        return args -> {
            Method method = So59546604Application.class.getDeclaredMethod("listen", String.class);
            MergedAnnotation<RabbitListener> mergedAnnotation = MergedAnnotations.from(method)
                    .get(RabbitListener.class);
            AnnotationAttributes attrs = mergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes();
            String[] queues = (String[]) attrs.get("queues");
            AbstractMessageListenerContainer container = (AbstractMessageListenerContainer) registry
                    .getListenerContainers().iterator().next();
            container.addQueueNames(queues);
        };
    }

}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@RabbitListener(returnExceptions = "true")
@interface RabbitListenerEpp {

    @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class, attribute = "queues")
    String[] value() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class, attribute = "queues")
    String[] queues() default {};

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll try it ASAP

Comment: Since we are still on Spring Boot 2.1.8 and then Spring 5.1.9, we don't have access to MergedAnnotations (introduced on 5.2)
So we can't use this workaround **but** we are currently upgrading the Spring version.  So we will use it. 
I just can't tell you if it's ok at the moment. 
Thanks